# Trying to get Selenium set up for Javascript in Windows: require statement not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, selenium-webdriver

I have installed the basics (nodejs, npm, selenium, python), which all claim to be there.  I'm not using (haven't installed) Eclipse or other IDE -- just trying to make sure the infrastructure is working first.

So I am trying a Javascript "hello world" program to run from the windows command line. Windows Jscript throws a runtime error 800A138F "Object Expected" at the first line of my script:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

How do I get Windows' Jscript to properly invoke nodejs' require functionality??

The script I'm writing is in the same directory as the geckodriver file and the nodejs, node_modules, and python directories.  Will I need to use any explicit paths?

Is the issue that I need to be running my script from node (e.g., command-line would be along the lines of 'node foobar.js')?

Comment: Yes you would need to run that with node